# Application Error Heroku - Problems with Deployment

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

Trying to figure out how to push my application to Heroku. I just did their Node.js tutorial successfully, and I am able to do `npm install` and `foreman start` to run my app locally just fine, but when I try to push it and open on the Heruko site it has an error, I assume I need to install something but I can't decipher the logs very well.

Here are my logs. (new to Git, NodeJS, and Heruko FYI, so sorry if I am missing something obvious)

```
$ heroku logs --tail
←[36m2014-12-29T15:38:08.188615+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
←[36m2014-12-29T15:38:08.188812+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
←[36m2014-12-29T15:38:08.897061+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2014-12-29T15:38:08.916161+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[33m2014-12-29T15:38:29.680490+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by myEmail.com
←[32m2014-12-29T15:38:36.597146+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=36191235-65e4-441e-9cfa-9498182d1834 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T15:38:36.810592+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=10f03d06-42d1-4119-999a-8337a8651222 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T15:38:40.082568+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=86f49b1b-d70f-444c-9927-4695b6b34e89 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T15:38:40.354619+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=38a9fb83-f441-4752-a1e9-e271db850383 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T15:38:43.300739+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=d579a34f-fb80-4cae-b33e-aa80f3850a69 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T15:38:43.574003+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=91f015a4-ee68-4e2e-b40f-49e47fbf0d99 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[33m2014-12-29T16:03:09.011875+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by myEmail.com
←[32m2014-12-29T16:03:15.311197+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=c6f7e40a-c7ac-4d68-9aa7-f3341a6cc098 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T16:03:15.594058+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=18a62541-e33a-4781-be06-045abe145879 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[33m2014-12-29T16:09:16.117810+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v4 created by myEmail.com
←[33m2014-12-29T16:09:16.117779+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy c90771b by myEmail.com
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:16.683226+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:18.193386+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `node server/app.js`
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.314638+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:340
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316610+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316611+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316613+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at require (module.js:380:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316615+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at module.exports (/app/server/config/express.js:38:13)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316617+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:15:28)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.314316+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.314898+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m throw err;
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.314906+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316618+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316620+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316621+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316608+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316605+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:19.316623+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:20.357443+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 8
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:20.375389+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:20.374306+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:22.796156+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `node server/app.js`
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.802405+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.803009+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m throw err;
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.803010+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804497+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.803003+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:340
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804500+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804501+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804504+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at require (module.js:380:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804503+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804507+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:15:28)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804508+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804509+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804512+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804511+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:23.804506+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at module.exports (/app/server/config/express.js:38:13)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:24.510417+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 8
←[36m2014-12-29T16:09:24.535039+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[32m2014-12-29T16:09:25.516484+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=435a24d0-3242-439b-9646-f9a754d0a0f1 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T16:09:25.835724+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=b0ea9325-dbc1-4001-b0d3-fc228043bf55 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[33m2014-12-29T16:11:13.788307+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by myEmail.com
←[32m2014-12-29T16:23:05.892581+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=3965fe7b-4155-49cf-81c8-56e20fe10ce3 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T16:23:06.183875+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=abdfb4e3-fc6c-4a18-85d0-4fb1653e0040 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[33m2014-12-29T16:24:17.858493+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 461491a by myEmail.com
←[33m2014-12-29T16:24:17.858493+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v5 created by myEmail.com
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:17.984165+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:20.032515+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `node server/app.js`
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.011870+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:340
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.012416+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014369+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.012169+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m throw err;
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014372+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014375+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.011468+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014382+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014383+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014385+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014386+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014377+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at require (module.js:380:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014374+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014379+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at module.exports (/app/server/config/express.js:38:13)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.014380+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:15:28)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.799791+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 8
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.808150+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:21.808844+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:23.672321+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `node server/app.js`
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.673230+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675428+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675431+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675436+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at module.exports (/app/server/config/express.js:38:13)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.673540+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:340
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.673797+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m throw err;
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.673804+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675438+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:15:28)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675424+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675429+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675443+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675445+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675434+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at require (module.js:380:17)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675441+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:24.675447+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:25.500954+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 8
←[36m2014-12-29T16:24:25.515899+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[32m2014-12-29T16:24:26.941578+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=b2c83aaa-778d-4334-8168-df88891294dd fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-12-29T16:24:27.226106+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-anchorage-3610.herokuapp.com request_id=4ffb26a0-d806-436b-8bf1-703cc39e17b7 fwd="64.255.74.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Did you place your package.json properly? Remember that's the app manifesto, so in order to deploy the app it should be updated with all the dependencies that your application needs.

Comment: I think so, it would not run/work locally if the `package.json` was not correct, right?

Comment: Depends. If you install the dependencies by itself, by running npm install, but you didn't put the option --save then, you have something installed locally and a different thing on the manifesto. Seems to be the issue you are having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your application is failing to load the `connect-livereload` module. You should only be using that in your local development environment. You probably have code something like this:

```
app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
```

in your `app.js` around line 15. You need to make sure you don't load this in the production environment. You could just wrap this line in an `if` statement something like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
}
```

This assumes that you've got an environment variable called NODE_ENV set to development, test or production depending on the environment you are running your application in.

Comment: So I modified the original code with yours under it, or do I need to add it to the first `if`? `if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
    if ('development' === env || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
    }
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));
    app.set('appPath', 'client');
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(errorHandler()); // Error handler - has to be last
  }`

Comment: Also, in my package.json I noticed instead of "dependencies" it was "Devdependencies", so I changed it to "dependencies", and it looks like its installing lots of stuff, but I think there are errors too. It prints so much that I cannot see the top of the command line anymore. Does it need to be "dependencies" and is there a way to output all the information it is spitting out?

Comment: Before using Heruko, I also used the command `grunt serve` to load my application, does that signify anything special?

Comment: So it looks like you already had an `if` statement in there to do what I was suggesting but it wasn't picking up the correct value for `env` in production (on Heroku). Without seeing your code its hard to say exactly what is going on. Heroku doesn't automatically set the NODE_ENV variable for you so you might be able to fix the problem by setting this by running `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production` from the command line and sticking with your original code. Otherwise you'll need to post at least the first part of your app.js file.

Comment: You should probably leave your package.json file as it was. `npm` distinguishes between dependencies that your application has in production from development-only dependencies. So `dependencies` are always installed, whereas `devDependencies` are only installed in your local dev environment. `connect-livereload` is something you only want locally so it belongs in `devDependencies`.

Comment: I am looking at **[https://medium.com/@3runjo/how-to-deploy-a-grunt-project-on-heroku-c227cb1ddc56](https://medium.com/@3runjo/how-to-deploy-a-grunt-project-on-heroku-c227cb1ddc56)** to see if it will help. What does it mean by this section? `// change the tasks in the list to your production tasks
grunt.registerTask('heroku',
    ['compass:dist', 'autoprefixer', 'imagemin']);`

Comment: `grunt serve` is just going to run the Grunt `serve` task locally so it shouldn't have a direct impact unless part of what it does is build your static assets (e.g. minify JavaScript and CSS). I would expect the `serve` to normally start up your local Express server and maybe livereload and perhaps watch for code changes and run tests.

Comment: Hmm okay. I guess I just gotta figure out what is going on with the dependencies... So stinkin' stressful :(

Comment: So the article on medium.com is referring to the pre-deployment `heroku` Grunt task. You would run this locally just before deployment by running `grunt heroku`. `compass:dist` will process your SASS (CSS) files, `autoprefixer` is about prefixing certain vendor specific CSS properties I think and `imagemin` will optimise your static images. These are just examples of tasks that you can optionally do to prepare your static content for deployment.

Comment: So I was able to sit down with a senior dev. The problem was that I was trying to deploy the entire project folder, and not the dist folder. >.> So yea haha. :) Thank you for your assistance though, I shall give you the answer reward for your help!